# Which is the maximum selectables rows in mysql with c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Hello
I am developening a c# app for selecting and comparing some data on db, on a table that has more than 500'000 records. I am using mysql connector, and I am going to do a :

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

from that table. 
My question is: Is recommended to use a select * without limit? Can this process gives problem if I select all 500000 records at once, or i should user limit for selecting records in groups?
I am asking that beacause in VB I got problems with this kind of select, with makes stops the program.

Thanks all.

**EDIT**: my select function:

```
public Object[] QuerySelect(String query)
{
    IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
    dbcmd.CommandText = query;

    IDataReader reader= dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        int fieldCount = reader.FieldCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
            ht.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader[i]);

        result.Add(ht);
    }
    reader.Close();

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Hi, if you explain exactly what you would like to do with those records retrieved you could get nice ideas on how to do it properly, Daniel is right a DataReader would be better than loading everything on a DataSet at once but I believe if some logic can be put in a stored procedure or could be done with a sliding window approach, all the better.

Comment: I have to read this rows, and for each row i have to check some values and then update this values under certaing conditions. i do not need to view this results, just process them, in a command promt app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` and `SqlDataReader` to read the data. In that case, it is not a problem per se, because you will request each row in a loop. But if you do something like reading through all rows and put the result in a list, yes, you will have a problem, because you are trying to put those 500,000 items into memory.

If you don't put the rows in a list, but process them somehow, so they can be garbage collected afterwards, you have no problem.

UPDATE:
You updated your question and showed the method you are using. That's exactly the scenario, that will get you into trouble, because it will result in an ArrayList instance with 500,000 Hastable instances.

BTW:
Nowadays you should use generics, e.g. [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead of ArrayList and Hashtable. It makes your code type safe.

Comment: For the moment I am using LIMIT in my query.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to solve the problem, do not force the user to split the table or reduce the number of records.

Try reading in a windows size you feel comfortable with and falls into your performance specifications. For example, read 100.000 records each time, process them, then store them and get the next set of 100.000.